# How to obtain the linear equation passing through two coordinates？

Tags: linear-algebra

```
{-Sqrt[5], 0}, {3/Sqrt[5], 4/Sqrt[5]}
```

How to automatically obtain the straight line equation passing through two points with the coordinates of the two points as shown above?

Comment: `pts = {{-Sqrt[5], 0}, {3/Sqrt[5], 4/Sqrt[5]}};
{a*x + b*y + c == 0} /. 
 FindInstance[
   And @@ {a*x + b*y + c == 0 /. Thread[{x, y} -> #] & /@ pts}, {a, b,
     c}, Reals, 2][[2]]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### 1. [`RegionMember`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionMember.html) + [`InfiniteLine`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InfiniteLine.html)

Use [`InfiniteLine`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InfiniteLine.html) and [`RegionMember`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionMember.html) to get a region member operator

```
ClearAll[regionMember]

regionMember = RegionMember[InfiniteLine@{##}] &;

regionMember[{-Sqrt[5], 0}, {3/Sqrt[5], 4/Sqrt[5]}]
```

[image]

```
regionMember[{-Sqrt[5], 0}, {3/Sqrt[5], 4/Sqrt[5]}][{x, y}]
```

[image]

If needed, Use [`Reduce`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce.html) to express `y` in terms of `x`:

```
Reduce[%, y, Reals]
```

> ```
> y == Sqrt[5]/2 + x/2
> ```

#### 2. [`Fit`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Fit.html)

Alternatively, you can use [`Fit`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Fit.html) as follows:

```
y == Fit[{{-Sqrt[5], 0}, {3/Sqrt[5], 4/Sqrt[5]}}, {1, x}, x]
```

> ```
> y == 1.11803 + 0.5 x
> ```

##### 3. [`LinearModelFit`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LinearModelFit.html)

```
y == LinearModelFit[{{-Sqrt[5], 0}, {3/Sqrt[5], 4/Sqrt[5]}}, x, x][
  "BestFit"]
```

> ```
> y == 1.11803 + 0.5 x
> ```

Comment: How to unify the linear equation into a general form: Ax+By+C==0?

Comment: @csn899, you can use `y - LinearModelFit[{{-Sqrt[5], 0}, {3/Sqrt[5], 4/Sqrt[5]}}, x, x][
   "BestFit"] == 0` to get the desired form directly. To transform `y == 1.11803 + 0.5 x` into the form desired, you can use `SubtractSides[y == 1.11803 + 0.5 x]`.

Answer (score 3):

Quite textbookish, but here it is.

```
Clear[x, y];
{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}} = {{-Sqrt[5], 0}, {3/Sqrt[5], 4/Sqrt[5]}}

y - y1 == (y2 - y1)/(x2 - x1) (x - x1) // Reduce[#, y] &
```

$$y=\frac{x}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}$$

Comment: How to unify the linear equation into a general form: Ax+By+C==0?

Comment: Take the solution above and `0 == %[[2]] - %[[1]]` ?

Answer (score 2):

3 quick possible examples

```
{P1, P2} = {{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}} = {{-Sqrt[5], 0}, {3/Sqrt[5], 4/Sqrt[5]}};
```

1.)

```
InterpolatingPolynomial[{P1, P2}, x] // Simplify
```

[image]

2.)

```
Det[{{x1, x2, x}, {y1, y2, y}, {1, 1, 1}}]
```

[image]

3.)

```
{a, b, d} = ResourceFunction["HessianLine"][{P1, P2}];
{a, b, d} . {x, y, -1} // Simplify
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

An alternative in parametric form (i.e. v1 + t(v2-v1))

```
lineParametric[{p1 : {x1_, y1_}, p2 : {x2_, y2_}}, t_] := p1 + t (p2 - p1)
```

e.g,

```
ParametricPlot[lineParametric[{{1,2},{3,4}},s],{s,0,1}]
```